# Jquery Mobile Syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have statement like this. But i have mulitple view details page like

1) Viewdetails1

2) viewdetails2

3) viewdetails3

4) viewdetails4

5) viewdetails5

---

i am wrting like this

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#viewdetails1",function(){
}


$(document).on("pageinit","#viewdetails2",function(){
}
```

...........

Can u provide me a statement which will allows the value viewdetails1 tot viewdetails10

I tried like this.

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#viewdetails"+/^[0-9]{1,10}$/,function(){
}
```

Comment: How about going by class instead of id?

Answer (score 1):

Give them all `class='viewdetails'`, then just call

```
$(document).on("pageinit",".viewdetails",function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use attribute [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","[id^=viewdetails]",function(){

}
```